# Nested for loops using row lags and multipliers defined in loop

Tags: r, for-loop

End goal is to take a dataframe and create a new column based on multiplication and addition of prior rows, i.e. if my multipliers are 0.1, 0.2, and 0.3, my addition is z + [lag(z) * 0.1] ,then I want to take column Z and transform it 3 times as such (skipping the first row):

```
z <- 1:4*10
df <- data.frame(z)
```

| Z | Z_0.1 | Z_0.2 | Z_0.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 30 | 32.1 | 34.4 | 36.9 |
| 40 | 43.21 | 46.88 | 51.07 |

I have been able to get the correct values by manually feeding in the rate and overwriting the existing column:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (i ==1)
      df[i,1] <- df[i,1]
    else
      df[i,1] <- df[i,1] + (df[i-1,1] * 0.1) 
  }
```

Separately, I can also create column placeholders for the new values:

```
for (i in seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1)) {
  cola <- paste('col', i, sep = "_")
  df[[cola]] <- 0
}
```

However, I cannot seem to combine these loops and get the outcome in the above sample table. I have tried this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  for (j in seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1)) {
    cola <- paste('col', j, sep = "_")
    df[[cola]] <- 0
    if (i ==1)
      df[[cola]] <- df[i,1]
    else
      df[[cola]] <- df[i,1] + (df[i-1,1] * j) 
  }
}
```

But it fills all the new columns with the same values for the whole column

| Z | Z_0.1 | Z_0.2 | Z_0.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 77.02 | 81.85 | 86.68 |
| 20 | 77.02 | 81.85 | 86.68 |
| 30 | 77.02 | 81.85 | 86.68 |
| 40 | 77.02 | 81.85 | 86.68 |

Appreciate any suggestions. I'm not married to for loops if anyone has an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this maybe?

```r
Z <- 1:4*10
y <- seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(Z)

for (i in 1:(length(Z)-1)+1){
  for (j in seq_along(y)){
    df[1,paste0('Z_', y[j])] = Z[1]
    df[i, paste0('Z_', y[j])] = Z[i]+(df[i-1, paste0('Z_', y[j])]*y[j])
  }
}
df
#>    Z Z_0.1 Z_0.2 Z_0.3
#> 1 10 10.00 10.00 10.00
#> 2 20 21.00 22.00 23.00
#> 3 30 32.10 34.40 36.90
#> 4 40 43.21 46.88 51.07
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>